Dynamic Bayesian Network with Temporal Hidden State
Can someone direct me to papers or Python packages which I can use to develop a dynamic bayesian network with temporal hidden states. I found packages that can handle discrete hidden states. But that's not my interest.
I would like to learn and implement.

I am quite new in this 'temporal hidden states' part, what do you mean with those?
Discrete hidden states would be the equivalent to HMM (Hidden Markov models), right? But that is not what you want.
Also, what is the relation between temporal and discrete? Are temporal states in continuous time? or in continuous space?

@OscarFlores I'm ideally looking for temporal states in continuous time.
